# Why does a .key file include P,Q,DP,DQ

Tags: encryption, rsa, digital-signature

By loading a pre-created .key file that includes an RSA Private Key only I noticed, that it contains the following numbers:

```
Modulus     (private modulus)
Exponent    (private exponent)
P           (prime exponent)
Q           (prime exponent)
DP
DQ
InverseQ
```

I am saving the key file somewhere, where storage is very small  (portable). I though of only saving Modulus and Exponent. I understand P,Q and E are necessary to create modulus and exponent, however:

**Question:**

What is the purpose in saving all this data to a .key file, when PrivateModulus and PrivateExponent are enought to *sign* and *decrypt* messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you need the *public key* `Modulus` and `Exponent` for encryption and the *private key* `Modulus` and `D` for decryption and signing.

`P` and `Q` are probably just added there for safety, since there is no efficient way to reconstruct them from the other given values. So in case your `D` gets corrupted, you can reconstruct it or if possibly a special implementation requires them for some Math-tricks to optimize the calculations.

The values of `DP`, `DQ` and `InverseQ` are used by some implementations to calculate *RSA* using the *Chinese Remainder Theorem* for speeding up the whole process.

```
DP       = D mod (P - 1)
DQ       = D mod (Q - 1)
InverseQ = Q^-1 mod (P - 1)
```

For more information on how that works, best check out this  [crpypto.stackexchange-question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/chinese-remainder-theorem-and-rsa) or the [Wikipedia-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

Comment: So if storage is the problem and the backup of the private key certainly exists, I can safely only use private key exponent d, public key exponent e and modulus n (which is same for both) and sacrifice computational speed.

_Would you maybe know, in Java, what does getPrimeP() return in Java?  getPrimeExponentP() and getPrimeP() are not the same values._

Comment: (I assume you are talking about `RSAPrivateCrtKey`) `getPrimeP()` returns `P` and `getPrimeExponentP()` returns `DP`. Yes, you can technically remove them, but it would not be a valid *PKCS1 Private Key Crt* anymore (since some values are missing).

Comment: There seems to be a small misconception here: `P` and `Q` are not **exponents** of `Modulus` but **prime factors**. I also corrected this in your question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I now know that all I need to use RSA is essentially modulus n, Private exponent D and public exponent E.

The names of methods in java `getPrimeP()` and `getPrimeExponentP()` confused me because they both had the P in the end and the Eclipse description did not clarify them.

Comment: Thank you also for explaining to me why there is redundant information in key files (faster computation and means to recreate the exponents).